# How can I remove UILabel's gray border on the right side?

Tags: uitableview, ios6, uilabel, border

I have added an UILabel to a custom cell's contentView. I met with a strange side effect. On the right border there is a gray edge. I don't know why. I just added an ordinary UILabel, I have done nothing else.

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
label.text = @"value1";
label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
[self.contentView addSubview:label];

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    UILabel *label = [self.contentView.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
    label.frame = CGRectMake(…);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know the reason, but the solution is to get rid of that gray edge to set the background color of the cell to clearColor.

> label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

Answer (score 25):

I know this is an old question but I have just come across this exact same problem, so I thought I could help someone else looking.

For me the problem was that I had floating numbers in my frames. The following fixed it for me:

```
CGRectIntegral( myLabel.frame )
```

Comment: Thanks for the floating number tip. I didn't want to change my frame size, so I created a `UIView` underneath the `UILabel`. I then changed the `backgroundColor` on the `UIView` and kept the `UILabel` `clearColor`

Comment: Thanks! I was having this same problem with UILabels in a UIPageViewController.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you need to set:

```
[label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

Next, set color that you want:

```
[label layer] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor].CGColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is still happening on iOS 12.

**Swift** version of *Ad Taylor* answer:

`myLabel.frame.integral`