# UITableCellView visible lines on top

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have an cell class that is inherited from `UITableViewCell`. It has next grey lines:
[image: screenshot1]

However if I don't set cell texts I don't see these lines:
[image: screenshot2]

So what can be the cause for this lines?

**UPDATE**

Here is code for my custom cell:

```
@implementation MDItemTableViewCell

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    NSString *fontName = selected ? self.selectedFontName : self.fontName;
    self.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:self.fontSize];
}

@end
```

**UPDATE 2**

Here is code for `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSArray *source = [(MDChoiceField *)self.field source];
    MDChoiceItem *item = source[(NSUInteger)indexPath.row];

    MDItemTableViewCell *cell = [(MDItemTableView *)self.fieldView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;

    NSString *string = NSLocalizedString(item.title, nil);
    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]
            initWithString:string];
    [attributedString addAttribute:NSKernAttributeName
                             value:@(1.2)
                             range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
    cell.textLabel.attributedText = attributedString;

    return cell;
}
```

And view one:

```
- (MDItemTableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MDItemTableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:self.fontName size:self.fontSize];
    cell.fontSize = self.fontSize;
    cell.fontName = self.fontName;
    cell.selectedFontName = @"HelveticaNeue-Light";
    cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithHexString:BLUE_COLOR];

    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
        [cell setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }

    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
        [cell setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }

    cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.bounds];
    cell.selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithHexString:LIGHT_BLUE_COLOR];

    return cell;
}
```

Sorry for so many lines.

Comment: try to, decrease height of label

Comment: your custom cell class code(where you set text and add line subview) should be there to check any mistake.

Comment: Why should I change height of cell? I want to fit all cells whole screen exactly

Comment: As blank title labels omit those grey lines, it has to be something withing your code. May be in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: @EugenMartynov Most probably your table is getting the separators set twice. Don't know where, but, that seems to be the cause.

Comment: @AlwaysThere, thanks I will try to check but, why setting separator twice paints it twice? As well why it is not painted when there is no text in the labels?

Comment: @EugenMartynov did you debug using View debugging tool introduce in XCode 6?

Comment: @EugenMartynov Would it be possible for you to upload a working sample demonstrating the bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the added lines are shorter than the table cell itself. If you turn on "Color Blended Layers" in the simulator Debug menu you can see that they seem to be the same length as the label. This suggests it's the *label*, not the cell, which is producing the oddity.

This question seems related: [How can I remove UILabel's gray border on the right side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13670181/how-can-i-remove-uilabels-gray-border-on-the-right-side)

And that suggests the following fix, added to `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`:

```
[cell.textLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

Answer (score 2):

A few settings will help you,

1. As Richa's answer, `self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;` It'll hide seperator (default one) from the table.
2. As user3781721 answer, `tableName.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];` will remove any empty cell. So there'll be a plain look of table.
3. In tableview's cellForRow datasource, `cell.clipsToBound = YES;` before return the cell.
4. If still not solve then increase your cell height little, may be by 5 and check.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in ViewDidLoad

```
tableName.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

Comment: Could you explain how `tableFooterView` produces lines?

Answer (score 0):

Using a 'Grouped' style UITableView will keep the table from showing these 'blank' cells if they are in fact empty. You can either declare this when you init the UITableView like this,

```
UITableView *myTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```

Or if you're using interface builder there's a drop down to change the style from 'Plain' to 'Grouped'

Answer (score 0):

Those lines are the default separator lines of tableView. Just set the separator style as NONE. write or use this line wherever you have declared your UItableView. Either in Xib  file or code.

```
self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

Update:1

```
- (void)viewDidLoad { [super viewDidLoad];
// This will remove extra separators from tableview
 self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
}
```

Use this, and let me know if it works or not.

Comment: This is not separators. If I set style to None I still see them

Comment: Can you tell me that what is the parent class of your ViewController ? Is it UIViewController or UITableViewController ?

Comment: Don't forget to call [super viewDidLoad];.

Comment: It is UIViewController

Comment: No, it doesn't work. After setting style to `None` I don't see blue separators but I still see grey lines